# Php array - Min

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, min

I have the following array and I am trying to find the minimum value of a...

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 18
            [f] => 0
            [f] => 0
            [l] => 61.60
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 38
            [f] => 0
            [f] => 0
            [l] => 11.99
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [a] => 28
            [f] => 0
            [f] => 0
            [l] => 3.40
        )
)
```

Should I use min or is a search going to be faster?

Comment: why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Have you tried use a foreach loop?

Comment: Unless this is a contrived example and you're doing this millions of times, I can't imagine minor performance differences will make any significant impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of arrays so you will need to use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) first to get all of the `a` values and then you can use `min()`:

```
$min = min(array_column($array, 'a'));
```

Full example:

```
$array = [
    [
        'a' => 18,
        'f' => 0,
        'f' => 0,
        'l' => 61.60
    ],
    [
        'a' => 38,
        'f' => 0,
        'f' => 0,
        'l' => 11.99
    ],
    [
        'a' => 28,
        'f' => 0,
        'f' => 0,
        'l' => 3.40
     ]
 ];

 $min = min(array_column($array, 'a'));

 echo $min;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/va8g3)